# Parse boolean expression in python

Tags: python, string, parsing, autosys

Currently, I have a Boolean expression which supports `&` (logical AND), `|` (logical OR), `(`, `)` (parentheses) operators along with status codes like `s, f, d, n, t` and job names.

The status codes represent the status of a job. (Eg: `s = success`, `f = failure`, etc...) and the job name is enclosed within parentheses with an optional argument which is a number within quotes.

Example i/p:

`( s(job_A, "11:00") & f(job_B) ) | ( s(job_C) & t(job_D) )`

My requirement is for such a given string in Python, I need to replace the existing job names with new job names containing a prefix and everything else should remain the same:

Example o/p:

`( s(prefix_job_A, "11:00") & f(prefix_job_B) ) | ( s(prefix_job_C) & t(prefix_job_D) )`

This logical expression can be arbitrarily nested like any Boolean expression and being a non-regular language we can't use regexes.

Please note: The job names are NOT known before-hand so we can't statically store the names in a dictionary and perform a replacement.

The current approach I have thought of is to generate an expression tree and perform replacements in the OPERAND nodes of that tree, however I am not sure how to proceed with this. Is there any library in python which can help me to define the grammar to build this tree? How do I specify the grammar?

Can someone help me with the approach?

Edit: The job names don't have any particular form. The minimum length of a job name is 6 and the job names are alphanumeric with underscores.

Comment: So I suppose the job names don't actually all have the form `job_<x>` already.

Comment: No, the job names don't have any particular form. They can be arbitrary

Comment: Are job names constrained to have a minimum length or come from a particular set of characters, or could you have a job named `s`, `f`, `d`, `n`, or `t` as long as it was inside a maximally nested set of parens?

Comment: We can assume the minimum length of a job_name is 6 and the job names are alphanumeric with underscores

Comment: Ah, AutoSys JIL :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that we can assume that job names are alphanumeric + _ and length at least 6, we should be able to do this just with a regex since it appears nothing else in the given strings look like that.

```
import regex

exp = '( s(job__A, "11:00") & f(job__B) ) | ( s(job__C) & t(job__D) )'
name_regex = "([a-zA-Z\d_]{6,})"  # at least 6 alphanumeric + _ characters
prefix = "prefix_"

new_exp = regex.sub(name_regex, f"{prefix}\\1", exp)
print(new_exp)
```